# Get hidden value set by JavaScript in JSF backing bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, ajax4jsf

I want to get a  JavaScript value in a JSF backing bean. I've tried the following:

JSF:

```
<h:inputHidden id="fileName" value="#{TestBean.fileName}" />
<a4j:commandButton id="button" value="Send Mail" action="#{TestBean.send}" onclick="onCall()"/>
```

Bean:

```
public String send() {
    System.out.println("File Name: " + fileName);
}
```

JS:

```
function onCall(){
    //value changes dynamically everytime this function is called
    document.getElementById('case:fileName').value = '123';
}
```

Problem with this code is: for the first time it is fetching empty string in backing bean
from the second time onwards it is getting previously generated value in the java script function.

Where did I go wrong and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this alternative working for you? `value="#{fileName}"` set the value's bean property use `setPropertyActionListener` or add the param as an argument to your method `#{send(fileName)}?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this code and it works fine on my machine. As I can see the code is not exactly copy-pasted, because there is mistake in `send()` method. It declares return type `String`, but it doesn't return anything.

Maybe your mistake is somewhere in the part of code you didn't copy here.

Comment: I think it's a red herring. It at least doesn't match with the problem description: "each click gives the previousy set value" :) If the return value was really missing, the code simply won't have compiled. By the way, I've seen more than often issues with `a4j:commandButton` like that, see also [this topic](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5390192). I won't be surprised if that's again the case. I'd upgrade RichFaces or report it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a4j's `commandButton` with a `actionParam` inside. Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534779/268016