# Set f:param value with JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

Is it possible to do:

jsf code (pseudo):

```
...
<f:param name="arg" value="document.getElementById('naming').text()">
<h:inputText id="naming"></h:inputText>
...
```

I mean approach,when `<f:param>` is set with JS.

Is it bad practice?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a4j's `commandButton` and `actionParam` to be able to pass a dynamic param back to the server.

Additionally, you need an attribute on your bean that will receive the param value.

Example:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{myBean.action}" value="Submit!">
    <a4j:actionParam name="arg" noEscape="true" value="getTheValue()" assignTo="#{myBean.myBeanArg}" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

Here `myBean.myBeanArg` will receive the value returned by the javascript function `getTheValue()`.

Notice the `noEscape="true"` attribute. This is needed because otherwise the data inside `value` would be enclosed in single quotes and escaped, resulting in no javascript execution. As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.1.GA/en/devguide/html/a4j_actionparam.html):

> It is possible to use JavaScript expression or function in the "value"
>   attribute. In this case the "noEscape" attribute should be set to
>   "true". The result of this JavaScript invocation is sent to the server
>   as a value of `<a4j:actionparam>`.

Answer (score 4):

`<f:param>` is server side stuff while javascript is client side. So you can't

You can use ajax `a4j` to do this ,

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.
You could change an attribute of a link for example and get this attribute in your action method ont he server side.

Alternatively you could use an hidden input field linked to an attribute in your bean.